# Add class after scrolling also need to work on refresh

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a working script which adds a class to the body after scrolling 80px.
This works but I need it to work too after having already scrolled and then refreshing the page.

So maybe replace the scroll part by position?

```
// fixed header
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 80) {
            $("body").addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(window).scroll` will only fire once a scroll event occurs. If you want to check for the scroll position when the page loads, you should do this outside of the `$(window).scroll` callback.

Comment: I did notice reloading works after removing the line:  `$(window).scroll(function() {` but then when scrolling stops working. Any idea to do this in a decent way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right. you need to check the event **and** the initial value:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 80) {
        $("body").addClass('fixed');
    }
    //no removing needed cause refresh did it
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it then doesn't work when I start scrolling. Or do I need to add it to the existing script? It then works but is it clean.

Comment: sure, you need both this and your event

Comment: Thanks posoppis, can accept your answer in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

`$(window).scroll` will only fire once a scroll event occurs. If you want to check for the scroll position when the page loads, you should do this outside of the `$(window).scroll` callback, like this:

```
function updateScroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 80) {
        $("body").addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $("body").removeClass("fixed");
    }
}

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(updateScroll);
    updateScroll();
});
```

Comment: thanks for using jquery (i'm just poor at jquery) :)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```js
// fixed header
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 80) {
            $("body").addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 80) {
            $("body").addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("fixed");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    document.querySelector(".fixed-top").classList.add("headerFix");
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".fixed-top").classList.remove("headerFix");
  }
}
```